# Transferring large table into one big file from snowflake to S3

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I have a snowflake table which contains around 2 billion rows and imported the table in CSV format into a S3 bucket using spark which created ~110 part files and total of around 300GB of data.

Now I want this data in single CSV file instead of those part files. I have tried to repartition/coalesce the pyspark dataframe into one partition and then writing the dataframe as single CSV file in S3 but that job never finishes.

```
hdfs_block_size = 512 * 1024 * 1024  # 512MB

write_options = {
    "compression": "snappy",
    "parquet.block.size": str(hdfs_block_size)
}

number_of_partitions = 1
# df = df.repartition(int(number_of_partitions))
df = df.coalesce(int(number_of_partitions))

df.write.mode("overwrite").options(**write_options).csv(path='s3://{}:{}@{}'.format(access_key, secret_key, s3_path), compression='gzip', sep='\t', emptyValue='""', nullValue='""', header=True)
```

Is there any efficient way of doing this?

P. S.: I am using databricks for this task.

Comment: I know this is a bit outside ths cope of the question as you've asked it, but what value do you foresee with creating a CSV file containing 2 billion lines? At that scale, CSV is almost certainly not viable for anything practically useful, especially if you're not applying any sort of compression to it or anything.

Comment: @esqew, I absolutely understand your concern and it's a valid one. The performance of reading/writing a 300 GB CSV file should be very poor. But that's what the client wants and all I need to do is to deliver them in a single file.

Comment: You should expect the resulting CSV to be much, **much** larger than 300GB if you're currently seeing 300GB in those Parquet partition files with `snappy` compression applied - a cursory glance at some sources indicates `.parquet.snappy` files can achieve somewhere around a 5.0 compression ratio, which would make your resulting, uncompressed CSV somewhere in the ballpark of 1.5TB (give or take). This operation will take an extremely significant amount of time to generate and upload to S3, even with a properly-specced Spark cluster. It's unlikely there's a more "efficient" avenue of doing this.

Comment: You do mention that you "*imported the table in CSV format*"; why is that CSV not sufficient to pass along to your client?

Comment: Have you considered [unloading from Snowflake to S3](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-s3)? There is an option to [unload to a single file](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations) by adding `SINGLE = true`